# Add ifelse() created variable to list of data frames

Tags: r, list, iteration

I want to know how to create a variable using the ifelse() command to a list of data frames.

I created 2 datasets, using the 300 top and bottom values from the `ggplot2::diamonds` dataset, called `diamonds_top300` and `diamonds_bottom300`:

```
# Loads packages
# ---- NOTE: making plots and diamonds dataset
if(!require(ggplot2)){install.packages("ggplot2")}
# ---- NOTE: for data wrangling
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}

# dataset creation
# ---- NOTE: selects only the top 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_top300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, 300, table))
# ---- NOTE: selects only the bottom 300 rows of the dataset
diamonds_bottom300 <- data.frame(dplyr::top_n(diamonds, -300, table))
```

I then used lapply and functions to create a list with 2 models, only differing on dataset used:

```
# Loads packages
# ---- NOTE: run mixed effects models
if(!require(lme4)){install.packages("lme4")}

## lists datasets to use
DATASET_list <- c("diamonds_top300", "diamonds_bottom300")

## creates model
# ---- NOTE: creates list object
freq_mlm_poisson_model <- 
  lapply(DATASET_list,
         function(data_list) wrapr::let(
           c(data_list_model = data_list), 
           (lme4::glmer(
             price ~ cut + color + carat + (1 | clarity) + (1 | depth),
             data = data_list_model,
             family = poisson()
           )
           )
         )
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
freq_mlm_poisson_model <- 
  setNames(freq_mlm_poisson_model, paste("freq_mlm_poisson_model", 
                                         DATASET_list,
                                              sep = "__")
  )
```

I then used lapply and functions to create the summary of these models in list form:

```
### creates summary model for list object freq_mlm_poisson_model
# ---- NOTE: creates list object
freq_mlm_poisson_summary <- 
  lapply(
    freq_mlm_poisson_model, 
    function(model_list) {
      summary(model_list)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
freq_mlm_poisson_summary <- 
  setNames(freq_mlm_poisson_summary, paste("freq_mlm_poisson_summary", 
                                           DATASET_list,
                                         sep = "__")
  )
```

I then turned the summary into a data frame with just the fixed effects information:

```
### turns summary list fixed effects into list of data frames
# ---- NOTE: creates object with summary of fixed effects
freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects <- 
  lapply(freq_mlm_poisson_summary, `[[`, 10)
# ---- NOTE: creates list object
freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df <- 
  lapply(
    freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects, 
    function(model_list) {
      data.frame(model_list)
    }
  )
# ---- NOTE: changes list object name
freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df <- 
  setNames(freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df, paste("freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df", 
                                           DATASET_list,
                                           sep = "__")
  )
```

Is there a way to use the ifelse() command or some other command to create variable called p_value_sign in each of the lists, which tell yes/no if the corresponding p value in the variable `Pr(>|z|)` is less that 0.05 (i.e., p < 0.05)?

Comment: Do you need a logical vector or 'yes', 'no' character column?

Comment: I would like to have a second variable that contains this information so that I can have both the numerical and other variable together. It can be a logical vector. the second variable could also give sign level (e.g., "marginally significant at p < 0.10", "significant at p < 0.05", etc...).

Comment: Thanks, you can try the updated soltuion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a `list` of `data.frame`, we can directly create the column with `transform` after looping over the `list` with `lapply`.  It may be better to keep it as logical vector because it helps in doing subsets easier

```
freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df2 <- lapply(
       freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df,
       transform, p_value_sign = `Pr...z..` < 0.05)
```

---

If we need multiple comparisons, use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df2 <- map(
   freq_mlm_poisson_summary_fixedeffects_df, ~ .x %>%
        mutate(p_value_sign = case_when(`Pr...z..` < 0.05 ~ 
          "significant at p < 0.05",
           ( `Pr...z..` < 0.10) & (`Pr...z..` >= 0.05) ~ 
           "marginally significant at p < 0.10", TRUE ~ "Not significant")))
```

Comment: Both your original and updated solutions elegantly solved the problem. Thanks so much!